# React Native máscara de TextInput usando Regex

Tags: react-native, text

Estou tentando fazer uma máscara de TextInput usando regex, e está mais ou menos assim:

[image: Screen capture]

Mas como é notável, primeiro o número aparece na tela e depois o state é atualizado e a tela muda de novo.

Código:

```js
const MoneyTextInput = ({onChangeText, ok}) => {
  let [text, setText] = useState('00,00');
  return (
    <TextInput
      value={text}
      keyboardType="number-pad"
      style={{
        width: '100%',
        height: '100%',
        fontSize: 22,
      }}
      onChange={({nativeEvent}) => {
        setText(prettifyCurrency(nativeEvent.text));
        onChangeText(prettifyCurrency(nativeEvent.text));
      }}
    />
  );
};
```

A função para formatar:

```js
function prettifyCurrency(value: String): String {
  if (!value) {
    return '00,00';
  }
  let newText = value.replace(/(\D)/g, '').replace(/^0+/, '');

  if (newText.length < 4) {
    for (let i = newText.length; i < 4; i++) {
      newText = '0' + newText;
    }
  }
  newText = newText
    .replace(/(\d{2}$)/g, ',$&')
    .replace(/(\d{1})(\d{3})([,])/, '$1.$2$3')
    .replace(/(\d{1})(\d{3})([.])/, '$1.$2$3')
    .replace(/(\d{1})(\d{3})([.])/, '$1.$2$3');
  return newText;
}
```

Tem alguma forma de fazer o TextInput esperar o `value` ser atualizado antes de mostrar alguma informação pro usuário?

Eu sei que o regEx não está lá grande coisa mas é porque eu sou iniciante nisso.

PS.: Estou usando `OnChange` porque me pareceu um pouco mais rápido do que o `onChangeText`

Comment: Será que se usar o preventdefault no keydown, ele nao impede que o texto seja escrito antes?

Comment: Eu procurei na documentação e eu acho que não tem como fazer isso, antigamente tinha como aumentar o buffer, mas já removeram isso